# Adjust size of window according to screen size/resolution

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, window

I am designing a window where I have a scroll viewer, but do not want to enable it on a large screen (say on a 22"). I want the scroll bar to be enabled **only when the screen size/ resolution is small** (maybe on a 15" when the dialog wont fit inside it). So I cannot use the following:

```
Window.SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight"
```

Also, my windows are made up of multiple user controls (so I cannot use the "SizeToContent" in individual User Controls either), hence the size of the window is dynamic (based on user selection).

How do I achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Post the relevant XAML. Use `MinHeight` or `MinWidth` or something.

Comment: I am setting the width => sizetocontent, height is static at 700 for now. this however doesnt fit inside a smaller screen, in which case i want the scrollbars to be enabled.